# how to show turn by turn navigation on MapBox

Tags: android, navigation, mapbox

I tried to follow navigation api (https://www.mapbox.com/android-docs/navigation/overview/#overview) but when I tried to add dependency it gave me this below error.

[image: enter link description here]

Please suggest best way to achieve navigation on mapbox.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A SNAPSHOT of our Android services is being used in:

`compile 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation:0.5.0'`

Please add in your project `build.gradle`:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide any example or any link for reference?

Comment: Issue should be resolved now in `0.6.0` as a SNAPSHOT is no longer being used. `compile 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation:0.6.0'`